# css- ripple list end effect

Tags: css

I try to make the ripple effect of the material design of lists that shows when try to swipe and this is the end and dont possible to swipe more. 
I made

```css
div{
    height: 300px; 
    width: 50px; 
    position: absolute; 
 
    border-radius: 0px 500px 500px 0; 
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 500px 500px 0; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 500px 500px 0; 
    background-color: black; 
    opacity:0.1;
  
  }
```

```html
<div>
  </div>
```

and it look like a box with round corner. I make the effect with js by change the width and the opacity. 
how to make the css more look like the effect ?

Thanks

Comment: It won't look like any kind of box with `display:none;`. Please provide some working code — either here or somewhere like jsfiddle.com — so we can see what you've done so far.

Comment: I change this to hide and to show this..

Comment: @squeamishossifrage I edited the question.

Comment: You need to show a sample of what exactly you mean by ripple effect.